# how to remove localhost:URL from alert box

Tags: javascript, reactjs

javascript alert box showing url + msg. i have not passed any thing but it shows url on the top of alert box. how can i remove this url ? The url is showing when my site is redirected from another site.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The `alert` function does not, and cannot, provide a title.